# How to check if a button was clicked, put a value on it and then use innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

basically I want to provide the user two options, Yes or No. For example, if he clicks the Yes button, then this information is saved and I can show what he chose at the end of the questionnaire.

I'm trying this way, but it's not working. At the end, nothing appears on the screen...

answer2-A = Yes Button

answer2-B = No Button

----------------------------//------------------------//-------------------------

```
document.getElementById('answer2-A').addEventListener("click", defineYes);
document.getElementById('answer2-B').addEventListener("click", defineNo);
};
function defineYes(){
    document.getElementById('answer2-A').value = 'Yes';
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('answer2-A');
};
function defineNo(){
    document.getElementById('answer2-B').value = 'No';
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('answer2-B');
```

Comment: document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('answer2-A').value;

Answer (score 1):

Few things to address - without seeing the HTML I assume the `value` property isn't set on the buttons. Additionally you can/should get references to the buttons and re-use them instead of querying over and over. You can use the `target` of the event to access which button you clicked.

```js
const yesBtn = document.getElementById('answer2-A')
const noBtn = document.getElementById('answer2-B')
const info = document.getElementById('info');

yesBtn.addEventListener("click", trackClick);
noBtn.addEventListener("click", trackClick);

function trackClick(e) {
  info.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<button id="answer2-A" value="Yes">Yes</button>
<button id="answer2-B" value="No">No</button>

<div id="info"></div>
```